I got Page Not Found error in treefrog framework
I got Page Not Found error in treefrog framework
Hi everyone, I'm newbie in treefrog framework, I did as turtorial in official website, but it's not working
https://www.treefrogframework.org/en/user-guide/tutorial/
`
tspawn scaffold relationship
DriverType: QPSQL
DatabaseName: test
HostName: localhost
Database opened successfully
...
Index page URL: http://localhost:8805/Relationship/index
`
`
make
treefrog -d -e dev
curl http://localhost:8805/Relationship/index
`
=> But I received Page not found message
Please tell me what I did wrong
